# Why doesn't this function get called on async postbacks

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to create loading screens for things that do postbacks on my page, specifically from a gridview's row click which does a postback and causes the entire page to load. I'd like to have some kind of loading page or loading snippets on the page. From the googling/stackoverflowing I've put this together from other posts and resources.

## script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        // Get the instance of PageRequestManager.
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        // Add initializeRequest and endRequest
        prm.add_initializeRequest(prm_InitializeRequest);
        prm.add_endRequest(prm_EndRequest);

        console.log(prm);
        // Called when async postback begins
        function prm_InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
            console.log("init sender " + sender);
        }

        // Called when async postback ends
        function prm_EndRequest(sender, args) {
            console.log("end sender: " + sender);    
        }

    });

</script>
```

## gridview/updatepanel

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="actAddPanel" runat="server" 
updatemode="Conditional" 
ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
  <ContentTemplate>
     <asp:GridView></asp:GridView>
   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

## problem

The script should let me know when a postback begins and ends so theoretically `prm_InitalizeRequest` will allow me to modify elements on the page to create custom load animations/details while a postback is occurring and the `prm_EndRequest` will let me know when a postback ends so that I know when to end that custom animation/detail.

I made the rows of the gridview triggers with `ChildrenAsTriggers="true"`, but when I do a postback I dont see my `console.log` messages which let me know that those functions are actually called. How do I get these functions to work?

Comment: Can you try to move javascript code out of $(function (){}) ? As far as I know, the $(function (){}) is fired only for initial load and subsequent partial updates from your update panel won't trigged $(function (){})

Comment: @Chih-HoAndyChou when I do that `Sys` is undefined

Comment: Try to move your script block after ScriptManager control. I just tried and it worked as expected.

Comment: @Chih-HoAndyChou I just tried and on my end still doesn't work as expected

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that in order for those functions to execute, they need to be triggered by an event. In my gridview I added `Triggers` and then my functions worked as expected.